# Why is function http_response_code() acting strange that was called after function header() in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers, fastcgi, http-response-codes

Well. I have a problem with `http_response_code()`, and I can't find an explanations.
If I use `header()` before `http_response_code()`, PHP returns HTTP-status which was set by `header()` and ignores any `http_response_code()`.

For example, I have a file:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
file_put_contents('./log',http_response_code(501).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('./log',http_response_code(502).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('./log',http_response_code(503).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
```

(I used `file_put_contents()` for preventing any output, because somebody can say, that it is the answer to this question)

I used default php-server (but the problem can be reproduced with NGINX):

```sh
php -S localhost:9985
```

There is request:

```sh
curl -D - http://localhost:9985
```

There is response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Host: localhost:9958
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 17:20:05 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.10
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And there is log:

```
404
501
502
```

The response includes first line:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

but I was waiting for `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable`.
The log file includes an expected data and it shows that `http_response_code` returned statuses correctly. But it didn't affect for HTTP response code.

I thought that a reason is some data which could have been sent to OUTPUT because I used `header()`.
But if I use `header()` twice, it doesn't create problems.
I changed my file:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
```

And repeated request:

```
curl -I http://localhost:9958
```

There was response:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Host: localhost:9958
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 17:26:08 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.10
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This works great!

The problem can be reproduced on PHP 7.2, PHP 7.4, PHP 8.
I found a comment https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php#125538 where it is. But there is apache. I should say that with if I use Apache, the problem is not reproducible for me.

**Please, describe, why the function (http_response_code) doesn't work how expect.**

*Please, don't advise not to use the function because I would want to know true reason for the behavior of the function (the sacred meaning).*

---

**Update:**
Bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81451&edit=2

Comment: Yes, I know it. That's not the problem.

Comment: `I used file_put_contents() for preventing any output, because somebody can say, that it is the answer to this question` But why? Why not do ONLY the http_response_code? It should not output anything

Comment: @aynber Because I wanted to show that `http_response_code` works. My log proves this. But it doesn't affect for HTTP Response Code )

Comment: Alright... So the issue is that `http_response_code()` does not override the status code generated by `header()` in certain SAPIs. For me, it works in mod_php, it fails in builtin server. So, honestly, it feels like a bug.

Comment: @aynber I made some edits to the question for making the problem clearer. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes! It feels like a bug, but if it is true, it is very strange because it can be reproduced in PHP 7.2, PHP 7.4, PHP 8. May be it has some other explanation?

Comment: Like [#76082](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76082), although this one in particular is fixed and related to NTS builds.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Maybe I should create a bug report on https://bugs.php.net/ ?

Comment: I took a quick look at the current source and couldn't make out a reason, why this shouldn't work. Yeah seems like you found a nice bug there. I'd go ahead and file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short explanation

It's because the status line passed to `header()` is prioritized over `http_response_code()` in some (all?) PHP SAPI implementations.

### Technical explanation (specific to PHP 8.0.10)

PHP tracks the status line and HTTP response code in two separate variables: `SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line` and `SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code`.

`header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')` sets `http_status_line` to "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/main/SAPI.c#L751) **and** updates `SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code` a few lines earlier, while `http_response_code(503)` **only** sets `SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code` to 503 [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/ext/standard/head.c#L369).

The code that PHP's builtin server uses for sending the headers can be found in the  `sapi_cli_server_send_headers` function ([php_cli_server.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L537)). In that function, we see that `SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code` is ignored when `SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line` is set. The [`sapi_cgi_send_headers`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L307) function used by PHP-FPM shows a similar story. The apache2handler SAPI [uses](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L149) *both* http_status_line and http_response_code. Theoretically, they could point to different statuses!

### Bug?

Maybe. But changing/fixing this behaviour after who knows how many years breaks backwards compatibility, so it should probably be left alone. It's probably best to avoid this situation altogether by sticking to either header() or http_response_code().

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
May be you now, why the problem missed in the official documentation ? 
I think that it would be so helpful.

Comment: Certainly, it doesn't affect all SAPIs and Apache module behaves differently. And if it's missing from documentation it's only because nobody has cared to do this research and push changes to the manual.